# Sequences of multiple backslashes rendering differently in preview vs published

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

I came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35121361/523612) with the following raw markdown source:

```
\\\ is an escape sequence that is === \

\? is not an escape sequence and is === \?

so '\\\\\\\' is '\\\' followed by '\\\' which is '\\\' (two escaped \\)

and '\\\\\' is '\\\' followed by '\' which is also '\\\' (one escaped \ and one raw \\)
```

When I view the answer, it looks like:

```
\\ is an escape sequence that is === \

\? is not an escape sequence and is === \?

so '\\\\' is '\\' followed by '\\' which is '\\' (two escaped \)

and '\\\' is '\\' followed by '\' which is also '\\' (one escaped \ and one raw \)
```

but when I go to edit it, the preview is different:

```
\\ is an escape sequence that is === \

? is not an escape sequence and is === ?

so '\\\' is '\' followed by '\' which is '\' (two escaped \)

and '\\' is '\' followed by '' which is also '\' (one escaped \ and one raw \)
```

(Of course, I am using preformatted text here to avoid corrupting the text even further!)

I wanted to fix the answer to use inline preformatted text for the examples and clarify the wording a bit, but for now I've abandoned the edit to showcase the rendering bug.

Comment: my brain hurts.

Comment: The [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35121361/revisions) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lz0C.png)) matches the preview and does not match what [is displayed on the questions/answers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82LIz.png).